# Trying to Bubble Sort in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

Trying to code so that a list of numbers that the user inputs is sorted through bubble sorting. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleSort
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n; 

        int[] list[];
        System.out.println("Please enter number of the elements to be sorted");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = keyboard.nextInt();

        for ( int pass = 1; pass < n; pass++)
            for (int i = 0; i < n - pass ; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i] > list[i + 1]){
                        int temp = list[n];
                        list[i] = list[i + 1];
                        list[i + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }

    }

}
```

I get the following error that says

```
The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]" for the line: if (list[i] > list[i + 1])

type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int" for line: int temp = list[n];

Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]" for line: list[i + 1] = temp;
```

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: There's at least one bug in your bubble swap. `int temp = list[n];` should be `int temp = list[i];`

Answer (score 1):

You just  declared a `2D` array using this `int[] list[];`. 2D array is an array of arrays and can be declared like this

```
int list[][];
int []list[];
int[] list[];
```

but your requirement is of 1D array which should be declared like this

```
 int[] list;
 int list[];
```

plus you forgot the initialization of your array and taking array data values from user, To initiliaze array

```
 n = keyboard.nextInt();
 list=new int[n]; // initialize array length
```

To take array value from user , you need to again loop `n` times and take input using `keyboard.nextInt();` to take all array values

see [this example](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort) to properly implement your logic

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and the example it helped so much

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.borntoinnovation.datastructure;

import java.util.Arrays;

//Sort between value like 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 :Suppose end is 5
//0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 ( 5th already sorted into their position
//0-1, 1-2, 2-3 (4th sorted)
//.... like that
public class SortingBubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] { 40, 10, -30, 45, 39, 32 };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1 - i; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        }
    }
}

/*
 * [40, 10, 45, 39, 32, -30] 
 * [40, 45, 39, 32, 10, -30] 
 * [45, 40, 39, 32, 10, -30]
 */
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.